# Search through Datatable for values that contain html c#

Tags: c#, html, datatable

I am trying to search through a csv file I loaded into a datatable.

The 2nd column contains some values with html. I want to search through and select only those values that contain html and their corresponding value in column 1.

How would I go about doing this? I know regex is not a good way.

```
        var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\classes.csv";
        var test = GetDataTableFromCsv(dir, true);
        var totalclasses = test.Rows.Count;


        Console.Write("Number of Classes: " + totalclasses);
        Console.WriteLine();
        test.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Studios";
        test.Columns[1].ColumnName = "Classes";
```

Here is a sample of part of the csv file that I read into the datatable.

```
3722,JHL Workshop Event 2
3722,Newcomers Workshop
3722,March Newcomer''s Workshop
3722,<FONT COLOR="#965C00"/>Pilates & Yoga
3722,Julian Retreat May 13 - 15, 2011
3722,<FONT COLOR="#965C00"/>Active Hatha Mix
3722,<FONT COLOR="#FF1CAE"/>Breathing & Meditation
3722,<FONT COLOR="#0000FF"/>Functional Movement Hatha Yoga (Blue)
3722,<FONT COLOR="#F00D3E"/>Active Hatha Flow (Red)
3722,<FONT COLOR="#CC2EFA"/>Gentle Restorative Mix (Purple) 
3722,Pre-Class offering for AGW Members:  Guided Meditation & Inspiration
3722,ACTIVE HATHA YOGA MIX
3722,Yoga, Breath and Meditation - "7 Spiritual Laws of Yoga"
```

I need the count of how many classes contain HTML, and then how many studios have classes that contain html

Comment: So you want to pull out the html, then parse values out of it?  Is the html consistant enough to be able to do that?  HTMLAgilityPack is the best thing to use if you want to parse HTML.

Comment: Are you sure it's not XML?  We can't help you parse it if you don't post a sample

Comment: No I really just need to get a count of how many of them their are and the corresponding studio.

Comment: Get a count of how many *what* there are?  Please phrase the answer in the context of the html column

Comment: Sorry. I need the count of how many classes contain HTML, and then how many studios have classes that contain html.

Comment: I think you'll have to use regex, there's no way to parse that out

Comment: @Jonesy, once its in the datatable, i dont think it would be too hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to detect html, you shouldnt need to parse it, just use string parsing for unique characters.  Regex here however might be more reliable.

```
var enumerableDT= test.AsEnumerable();
var classesWithHTMLCount = enumerableDT.Count(x => x["Classes"].ToString()
                                                               .Contains("/>"));
var studiosWithHTMLCount = enumerableDT.Where(x => x["Classes"].ToString()
                                                               .Contains("/>"))
                                       .GroupBy(x => x["Studio"])
                                       .Count();
```

Comment: Okay so I ran it on the entire DataTable which contains about 106,000 records. When I have contains("/<") I get classeswhtml=14, studioswhtml=3 but when I do it your way "/>" I get classwhtml=160 studioswhtml=18. Why are these different? @paqogomez

Comment: @hatfieldac `/` is a string escape character.  It looks like that you are escaping the `<` character instead of searching for `/<`.  If you want to use that string to search on try `//<`

Comment: When I try '//<' I get zero values returned.

Comment: @hatfieldac, I chose the closing html tag because it seems like it would be unique.  Do you know what the count is supposed to be?

Comment: Haha no that is what I am trying to find. Unfortunately it is not unique as some values contain > but do not have html in them. Such as this 26092,July Early Morning Practice (16th Jul >1st Aug) @paqogomez

Comment: @hatfieldac They may contain `>`, but not `/>` right?

Comment: Correct! So this should be the correct count then? @paqogomez

Comment: @hatfieldac Well, I cant see your data, but I'd assume so.  If you're not sure, you should probably do more testing to figure it out.  Just query for those that `Where(x => !x["Classes"].ToString().Contains("/>"))` (not contains) and look at the data in the debugger.  Should give you a good idea.  Good luck!